# Pyodbc.connect (), a method or a function?

Tags: python, pandas, function

is Pyodbc.connect () a method or a function? People use these two words interchangeably. Please note that I am using it in Pandas for database connectivity

Comment: This seems like more of a general Python terminology question than anything about pandas. Some people (myself included) consider a method to be a type of function, although that definition is sketchy. If `Pyodbc` is a class, `Pyodbc.connect()` is calling a class (or static) method.

Comment: methods -> functions defined on objects. All methods are functions but not vice versa. If you call obj.f(), it's a method, if you call f() it's either a function or a class (internally the same thing).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!